# In Java, how to set file owner to root?

Tags: java, nio, privileges, elevated-privileges

I'm using MacOS and this is my sample code:

```
@Component
public class HealthFileSystemServiceImpl {
    public HealthCommonConf saveYml(HealthCommonConf healthCommonConf) throws IOException {
        Files.setOwner(Paths.get(myFilePath), FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService().lookupPrincipalByName("root"));
    }
}
```

And I get this exception message:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp/jmuser/healthService/monitor/Test-Jmsight-id_Test-Health-Name.yml: Operation not permitted

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setOwners(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:268)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setOwner(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.setOwner(FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.java:100)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.setOwner(Files.java:2163)
```

How can I solve this?

---

**Edit**

**Environment**:

1. I'm using IntelliJ, and I'm trying to run my JUnit test file.
2. `healthTcpConfRepository.findById(1L)` returns `true`.
3. `myFilePath` exists.

---

```
@Autowired
private HealthFileSystemServiceImpl healthFileSystemService;

@Test
public void saveConf() throws IOException {
    healthFileSystemService.saveYml(healthTcpConfRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null));
}
```

Comment: Is your application running as `root` or superuser?

Comment: @Azeem Yes. by superuser

Comment: Can you please add steps in your question also about how you're running this? From terminal or IDE?

Comment: @Azeem Sure. I edit my question.

Comment: Good. Is your IntelliJ running as superuser? Did you try running it from terminal as root?

Comment: Wow. It is success without exception... I think it is my mistake. Thanks for @Azeem

Comment: Cheers! :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that your IDE i.e. IntelliJ IDEA is running with `root` privileges while you execute your application.

If you're running it from a command line / terminal then it should also be executed with `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Azeem.

When i run as root with terminal, it is passed.

```
root# mvn clean test -Dtest={myPackage}.HealthFileSystemServiceImplTest#saveConf
```